# How to replace values in Pandas Dataframe in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas Dataframe which look like this:

```
       feat_1   feat_2  feat_3  ...  ... 
target  10       23       15    
UL      0.5      4        7 
LL     -0.5     -4       -7
```

Where UL and LL stands for upper and lower limit and this is index.
I want in loop replace values of those with calculated limits like this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    UL = df[column].loc['target'] + df[column].loc['UL']
    LL = df[column].loc['target'] + df[column].loc['LL']

   ???
```

So my desired output would look like this:

```
       feat_1   feat_2  feat_3  ...  ... 
target  10       23       15    
UL      10.5     27       22    
LL      9.5      19       8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use non loop solution like using only [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[['UL', 'LL']] += df.loc['target']
print (df)
        feat_1  feat_2  feat_3
target    10.0    23.0    15.0
UL        10.5    27.0    22.0
LL         9.5    19.0     8.0
```

working like:

```
df.loc[['UL', 'LL']] = df.loc[['UL', 'LL']] + df.loc['target']
```